# New-ADReplicationSubnet : The object name has bad syntax

Tags: powershell

I don't understand why this simple PowerShell script below fails:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users\me\Desktop\files\sitesTest.csv" | ForEach-Object { 

     New-ADReplicationSubnet -Name $_.Name -Site $_.Site -Location $_.Location }
```

but the worst comes when I simply run a

```
New-ADReplicationSubnet -Name "10.66.208.129/27" -Site MYSITE
```

and I get the same error message!! Which is:

```
New-ADReplicationSubnet : The object name has bad syntax
At line:1 char:1
+ New-ADReplicationSubnet -Name "10.66.208.129/27" -Site MYSITE
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=10.66.208.12...l,DC=mine,DC=org:String) [New-ADReplicationSubnet], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8335,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADReplicationSubnet
```

Comment: Perhaps it's expecting the first IP in the block, try `-Name "10.66.208.128/27"` instead

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen you know the saying that goes like "Look at the moon not the finger pointing at the moon"... that is exactly what I was doing!! many thanks indeed

Comment: how do I set the question as solved by Mathias??

Comment: You're welcome! I've added a proper answer you can accept now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the DSA expects the subnet name to come in the format: `<first IP in Block>/<prefix>`, so try:

```
New-ADReplicationSubnet -Name "10.66.208.128/27" -Site MYSITE
```